# get mean date of dates in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe and I need to calculate the mean of a group of dates because I need to match it later with one date of another dataframe.
this is my example data frame:

```
variables =c("a", "a", "a", "b","b", "b", "c","c", "c")
date_measured = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-08","2021-07-20", "2021-08-03","2021-08-12","2021-08-25",  "2021-09-03","2021-09-12","2021-09-25" )
values=c(1,4,6,9,8,2,4,11,14)

dataframe <- data.frame(variables, date_measured, values)
```

and I need to get the mean date of the column date measured grouped by variables,
I tried with

```
dataframe1 <-dataframe %>%
group_by(variables) %>%
summarise(mean_date= mean.Date(as.Date(date_measured)
```

but it returns the same column as date measured.. how can I do it in another way?
thanks a lot!

Comment: `dataframe %>% 
  group_by(variables) %>% 
  summarise(meanDate = mean(as.Date(date_measured)))` works as expected for me

Comment: so instead of mean.Date to use only mean?